# MinGW libraries issues

Tags: c, mingw

In the process of porting a C project from Linux to Windows

Have installed MinGW

Have compiled my shared library using a Makefile

This produces `libExample.so`

Now I'm trying to link this shared library to a test harness so I can see if everything is working as expected

In the harness Makefile I specify the location of the library, e.g. `-LE:/libExample_dir` and the name of the library `-lExample`

but its complaining it cannot find the library, i.e. linker is failing with `cannot find -lExample` - is there some difference with windows regarding `.so` and `.dll` or perhaps pathnames that I am missing?

Comment: I think I maybe an idiot and need only to change the ext from .so to .dll... just testing now

Comment: I can confirm I am an idiot...

Comment: You can answer your own question so other people can benefit from you finding the solution.

Comment: @colin OK - wasn't sure whether that was acceptable SO etiquette

Comment: perversely having managed to compile the harness against libExample.dll (I had to jump through a few __declspec(dllexport) hoops first) it is now complaining it cannot find libExample.so when trying to run the harness, bizarre?

Comment: just to clarify, when I run the Makefile to link the harness against the library it complains if libExample.dll is not there, but when I run the resulting harness .exe it complains if libExample.so is not there - the only way I can get it to work is by having copies of the library with both extensions in the same dir.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using MinGw to compile C code to produce a shared library, remember to rename the output from `libExample.so` to `libExample.dll` otherwise the linker will fail to find your library

Answer (score 2):

You need to fix the make file so shared libraries are generated with a `.dll` extension.

If I had to guess, I'd say that while renaming the generated file is enough to make the linker happy, the loader still expects the `.so` extension because that's the name that was compiled in...

Comment: i'll give that a try and report back - makes a lot of sense, have fried my brain today with adventures in Win32 land after a long time away