# Qt: mingw compiled library does only work with both library.so and library.lib file present

Tags: qt, g++, mingw, shared-libraries

I compiled a library using the MinGW toolchain provided with Qt 5.0.2 on Windows. As a result I received a library.so file. First I failed using the library in a Qt application, but now I found out that everything works fine when I make a *copy* of the `liblibrary.so` file and call it `liblibrary.dll` or `liblibrary.lib` (which is the only file ending supported by the add library wizard in QtCreator).

Now I wonder if this is normal or if I should change something in order not to have both files (which are exact copies). Leaving one away makes the application crash during start up. I added the library as follows to my Qt pro file:

```
LIBS += -L"../path/to/library" -llibrary
INCLUDEPATH += $$quote(../path/to/library)
```

EDIT: I compiled the library using the MinGW of Qt, not as Qt project but using mingw32-make and the provided Makefile. As a result I get the `liblibrary.so`.

EDIT: It seems to work also when renaming the copy to liblibrary.dll instead of .lib. But still, I need two files to make the application work -- the .so and the .dll.

Chris

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's weird, I think you should get a *.a and *.dll files when building a shared lib with MinGW on Windows, as said in the [documentation](http://qt-project.org/wiki/How_to_create_a_library_with_Qt_and_use_it_in_an_application):

> In windows, MinGW will output .a and .dll, MSVC2010 will ouput .lib and .dll. In linux, MinGW will output .so, .so.1, .so.1.0 and .so.1.0.0 – .lib, .a and .so are import libraries.

You definitely shouldn't rename your file!

Be careful to:

- not to include the "lib" prefix after "-l" in your project file.
- put everything after after "-l" in lower case as you're on Windows
- not adding any extension to your library name after "-l"
- add and reference the .h file used in your library

A real example using QtWebsocket lib:

```
INCLUDEPATH += "$${PWD}/include/"

LIBS += -L"$${PWD}/libs/" -lqtwebsocket
...
HEADERS += ... \
       $${PWD}/include/QWsSocket.h \
       ...
```

In my `include/` folder, I have the following file:

- `QWsSocket.h` (taken from original project - required)

In my `libs/` folder, I have the following file:

- `libQtWebsocket.a`
- `QtWebsocket.dll`

**Edit:** I struggled with this too initially. Have you tried to build your lib as a static lib instead (`CONFIG += staticlib` in your library project)? This might help you getting you `*.pro` file right before switching to using the shared library.

**Edit 2:** Ok, the fact that you get a `*.so` file is still a bit odd. In [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9772545/mingw-libraries-issues)
the user has the same issue as you and keep both files, which is just a workaround. According to [a later answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9775745/1412348) it seems that you need to modify your makefile to generate a file with the proper extension. Maybe this will help: http://www.mingw.org/wiki/sampleDLL

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Maybe I was unclear: I compiled the library not as Qt project, but using the MinGW provided with Qt. So maybe I need to change something in the Makefile of the library? I want to use the library with a Qt project, though. I followed all the four rules you listed under 'be careful to'.

Comment: Thanks a lot, especially for the link to the other question, unfortunately I did not find it before. So the solution is very easy: just rename all .so to .dll in the Makefile of the library.